# Google Analytics Views use like segments

Tags: google-analytics, architecture

Is there a concern with Google Analytics views overlapping? In the sense, Can I use GA Views like I use segments, were i can just throw one on top of my report and limit and extend data pull?

Based on my understanding, the best practice around Views is to set it up in such a way that data between multiple views should not be the same (for example: web traffic from CA and web traffic from US).

Am i right in assuming this

Answer (score 0):

You can create the views with the filters you want most.

In your case it makes sense to create a view with all the countries data and if you want a filtered view of each country you want to see separately, including data by **Country** dimension.